# How do I find distribution of a very large dataset

Tags: statistics

I have a airline.csv file which has around 1 million entries,what can I do to find the distribution of such a large dataset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of probability distributions in statistics. So you need to select a distribution according to the predictions that needs to be done using the existing dataset. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_fitting

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on "you need to select a distribution according to the predictions that needs to be done using the existing dataset. ", I am new to this area ,so please can you provide details

Comment: I think you have a dataset related to airline. This could be flight delay, ticket prices, passenger counts or any other useful data that needs to be analysed. So you might need to do some predictions or some analysis from the existing data.

Comment: yes I have airline dataset,so what prediction and what analysis should I do on it? I mean what would you have done to know which distribution this dataset fits into? Can you please provide steps and details?

Comment: directly form your dataset and you can plot some histograms and charts.  If you need to forecasts from your existing data you need to find a distribution. Most common is normal distribution that use for classic test score at college. Please load your data to a statistical software package and try different distributions.

Comment: First you need to have any clue about the dataset(what columns means). Check the data values are Discrete or Continuous. Try to plot a histogram. If you use any statistic software like R. you can try different distribution and test which is the best distribution for your data.  [link](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Ricci-distributions-en.pdf)

Comment: Ok so plotting a histogram manually for 1 million entries is impossible,so to do this I should use the statistic software something like R ,correct?

Comment: latest versions of excel can load 1M rows per sheet I guess but painful to process. There are software packages which can plot millions of records. Anyway u can take as sample and plot graphs.If you use R (which is free), you can try statistical analysis easily. Also u can use library functions like [fitdistr](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/MASS/html/fitdistr.html)(x, "gamma") to check whether distribution fits gamma distribution as example.  In real world datasets its hard to say which distribution fits well. Some may have mixture of distributions.

Comment: Thankyou so much yohan_f this piece of information was really helpful,thanks a ton :)